# CSS media prints 3 blank pages

Tags: css, html, printing

I use Bootstrap 3, just to know. I cannot get rid of 3 blank pages after the first one. Don t know what is causing this problem.

HTML:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" id="post_accesorii">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cod</th>
        <th>Denumire</th>
        <th>Cantitate</th>
        <th>U.M.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <?php
    while($rowD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {   
      foreach ($rowD as $col => $val) {
        if($val != "" && $val != "0" && $col != "nr_fisa" && $col != "id") {
          $findum = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `stocuri` WHERE `cod` = '$col' AND `post1` = 'Accesorii'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
          $rowum = mysqli_fetch_array($findum);

          echo "<tr class='piesa_folosita'>";
          if($col == $rowum['cod'])
            {
             echo "<td>" . $col . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $rowum['denumire'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $val . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $rowum['um'] . "</td>";
            }
             echo "</tr>";
            } else {
          }
        }
      }
   ?>

   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
   <tr>
   <th>Cod</th>
   <th>Denumire</th>
   <th>Cantitate</th>
   <th>U.M.</th>
   <tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>

<a href="javascript:window.print()" class="btn btn-primary">PRINT</a>
```

print.css:

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 99% !important;
  }
  #post_accesorii, #post_accesorii * {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 99% !important;

  }
  #post_accesorii+#post_accesorii {
    page-break-before: always;
}
}
```

In print preview, I have 3 blank pages after the first page with my table. I tried several solutions to remove them but none worked.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `height: 99% !important;` might be the problem, because the `<body/>` does not have parent

Comment: It s not from there. What I did, was to set html, body {
    display: none;
  } but now my table is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Your last print rule implies that there is more than one element that has the ID `#post_accesorii` .  This should not be the case and is invalid HTML: IDs must only appear *once* in a page. So maybe that's the reason for your problems (I don't know what is around the code you posted, so that's all I can say).

To avoid that, make it a class instead of an ID: `.post_accesorii` and assign that to the HTML `table` tag/s via `<table class="post_accesorii">`